# How to store a long data like RFID tag data in a postgres database?

Tags: java, postgresql

How to store a long data like RFID tag data in a postgres database? 
The RFID reader gives the BCD data converted into hexadecimal data of 24 bytes.

Example:cd00320000a4002a00001042 is the converted data given by the reader.

Answer (score 1):

There are many possibilities to do that.

It somewhat depends on what you want to do with the data.

But there seems also to be some confusion on your side: As the hex dump above has 24 digits, it is only 12 bytes worth of data, not 24. Which could be stored as 3 ints, or as string "cd00320000a4002a00001042", or ...

Question: How is the data stored in your java program, i.e. of what type is a variable where RFID data is stored?

Comment: agree.. a little vague on the question. my suggestion would be to store it as a string as well.